# How to center segmented control on top of a toolbar in Swift?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbar

How would you center a segmented control placed on top of a toolbar? xCode is not showing the blue lines when resizing the segmented control. How can I accomplish that with swift in order to keep all views (portrait or landscape) center regardless of the size class?

I'm able to resize the portrait but I don't think I should do it by eye like on

[image: Pic]

Here is the problem.

[image]

Comment: If you try to add the segmented control inside a TableView Row, it will try to take maximum space. But if you put it on a normal view controller, the blue guide lines will appear normally.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to resize it or center it?

In order to center, drag Flexible Space controls to the left and right of the Segmented Control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution,you can do it easily by setting constraints.

1.Select your segmented control

2.Align to the center,using arrow key at any position u want.

3.Delete all constraints that you have made before,select the segmented control again and click "Resolve Autolayout Issue" button near "Pin"

4.Choose "Add Missing Constraints"

Now u can set it the center at your tool bar.

[Here](http://puu.sh/iYriy/ae2c092c54.png) , hope this help...